# Quarto figure subcaptions ERROR: compilation failed- error Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

Tags: r, quarto

I'm using Quarto with R to write my dissertation, and I've encountered a complication error `ERROR:  compilation failed- error Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. l.3650 }` specifically when I try to use sub-tables. This error only occurs when rendering to PDF. I can render to HTML and to Word just fine.

I isolated the problem at this R code chunk:

```
{r, display_aov_tbls}
#| label: tbl-aov_tbls_avg_vals
#| tbl-cap: ANOVA table of fixed effects for linear mixed effects models. Controlling factors of age, sex, and upper VO~2~ bound are excluded for brevity. * p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001, ns (not significant).
#| tbl-subcap: 
#| - "VT~1~"
#| - "RC"
#| layout_nrow: 2

kable(aov_tbl_vt1) %>% 
    kable_classic(full_width = FALSE, html_font = "Times New Roman")

kable(aov_tbl_vt2) %>% 
    kable_classic(full_width = FALSE, html_font = "Times New Roman")
```

I did my best to follow the same syntax provided in the [Quarto documentation (scroll down to just above **Grid Tables** for an example)](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/tables.html).

If I change this code chunk to just a single table (see below), the document renders as expected.

```
{r, display_aov_tbls}
#| label: tbl-aov_tbls_avg_vals
#| tbl-cap: ANOVA table of fixed effects for linear mixed effects models. Controlling factors of age, sex, and upper VO~2~ bound are excluded for brevity. * p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001, ns (not significant).

kable(aov_tbl_vt1) %>% 
    kable_classic(full_width = FALSE, html_font = "Times New Roman")
```

I'm guessing that the `l.3650` part of the error message refers to "line 3650", but I have no idea how to get to that line, as I only have ~775 lines in this chapter of my dissertation.

Is this a bug or something I can fix by adjusting some deeper LaTeX, Quarto, R, or Pandoc settings? I have a few custom `.tex` files and some custom `_quarto.yml` settings to meet the formatting requirements required by my university. Please let me know if I need to include those to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing Rmarkdown code block notation with Quarto code block notation, and you perhaps have duplicate code block labels. Does replacing `{r, display_aov_tbls}` with `{r}` work?

Comment: I tried going to just `{r}` and still no luck.

Comment: Is the issue specific to content in the object `aov_tbl_vt2`? Or can you render that as a single table as well? If you can make this a minimal, single chunk, fully reproducible example _(ideally using a built-in data set like `mtcars`)_ then you are much more likely to receive help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I went on vacation and your reply got buried in my email. I tried Julian's suggestion from the thread below and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you error is the `layout_nrow: 2`, change it to `layout-nrow: 2` and it should work:

````
---
format: pdf
---


```{r, display_aov_tbls}
#| label: tbl-aov_tbls_avg_vals
#| tbl-cap: ANOVA table of fixed effects for linear mixed effects models. Controlling factors of age, sex, and upper VO~2~ bound are excluded for brevity. * p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001, ns (not significant).
#| tbl-subcap: 
#| - "VT~1~"
#| - "RC"
#| layout-nrow: 2
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(mtcars)) |> 
    kable_classic(full_width = FALSE, html_font = "Times New Roman")

kable(head(mtcars)) |> 
    kable_classic(full_width = FALSE, html_font = "Times New Roman")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Good catch on the `_` vs. `-`. I tried changing to `#| layout-nrow: 2` and I'm still getting the `ERROR: compilation failed- error Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` error message.

Comment: Have you tried my minimal example? Does that work for you?

Comment: I apologize for the long overdue reply. I went on vacation and only recalled this now. I tried your minimally reproducible example using a new Quarto project saved to my desktop. I'm still getting an error. Here is some of the Background Jobs output

`Rendering PDF
running xelatex - 1
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode

updating tlmgr

updating existing packages
ERROR: 
compilation failed- error
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.261 }`